# Memoization in ASP.NET (worrying about static variables and sessions)

Tags: c#, asp.net, memoization

I'm starting to use an implementation of memoization in my ASP.NET application, that goes like this (really straightforward, I think):

```
public static class Memoizer
{
    public static Func<A, B, R> Memoize<A, B, R>(this Func<A, B, R> f)
    {
        var map = new Dictionary<Tuple<A, B>, R>();
        return (a, b) =>
        {
            var tuple = new { a, b };
            R value;
            if (map.TryGetValue(tuple, out value))
                return value;
            value = f(a, b);
            map.Add(tuple, value);
            return value;
        };
    }  
}
```

For 'normal' applications it's all ok, I already tested it, but now I would like to modify this code to be used in an ASP.NET application.
The problem I'm wondering about is that I would need to save the map object in the Session variable, since I don't want different users mix up values/function calls.
Right now, if I Memoize two different functions, with this code I generate two different static variables, and this is ok, but if I save them to the Session, I have to differentiate them for some identifier (function name?), otherwise they would share the same map object in the Session.
I'm a bit puzzled, I don't know if I'm missing something...
Andrea

Comment: offtopic: since when 'var tuple = new { a, b };' is equivalent to Tuple<T1,T2> ?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you show is completely thread safe in itself. If you use it like intended and create a function that you don't share with other threads, then it's not a problem.

If you keep the function from one request to the next, then you are not actually using it for memoization, then you are using it for caching.

Using memoization for caching is terrible. The memoized function never forgets anything, so the longer your application runs, the more the map that the function keps will grow. Eventually it can't grow any more because it can't allocate more memory, and the application will crash.

If you want to cache the results, you should use proper caching instead, where the cache can throw away results that hasn't been used in a long time, or when the memory is needed for something else.

Comment: memoization for caching is ok if you have a small set of input values but operation is computationally very expensive. And yes, I usually add a method to purge memoised data.

Comment: @voroninp: Yes, that would be the special case where it would work.

Comment: Good input, @Guffa: I'll look into 'proper caching', I absolutely didn't think to this...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save memoized functions in a session.

You need to save each function in some application wide storage:

```
private static Dictionary<TUser,Fumc<A,B,R>> memoizedfunctions = new Dictionary<TUser,Fumc<A,B,R>>();
```

Where TUser is some type allowing you to discriminate users (e.g. login name).
By the way,  each user can have more than one initiated session, do you really want them to have separate functions?

You can store maps, not memoized functions, but the idea is the same, you somehow need to tie data to the request.